# how to add a table name described at the top to be duplicated for each row of a table in awk

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

I've a  file that has the below kind of o/p in tabular form:

```
00 102 | table1|
1 | a|b|c
2 | c|e|f
00 101 | table100|
0 | a|b|c|e|d 
23| 0|1|2|3|4
34| 1|2|3|4|5
```

Now, if the give the above file as input, I should get my output as follows:

```
00 102 | table1|1 | a|b|c
00 102 | table1|2 | c|e|f
00 101 | table100|0 | a|b|c|e|d 
00 101 | table100|23| 0|1|2|3|4
00 101 | table100|34| 1|2|3|4|5
```

So, in the above file, the table name record can be identified with table and all the records underneath it until it encounters next "table" record are its records.So, in the input file, there are two tables one with two records and other with three records each. Just need to concat the table name record with its records under it.
 Can somebody suggest better shell script that does this.

Answer (score 2):

using awk

```
awk '/^00/{s=$0;next}{print s,$0}' file
```

Comment: +1 but lose the `,` between `s` and `$0` on the print line as the OP isn't asking to add a blank char between the header and the records.

Answer (score 1):

you might try:

```
awk -F\n -v RS="00 " '{for (i=2;i<NF;i++) print RS $1 $i}' file
```

Comment: You should mention that this solution is gawk-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Some like this `awk` should do:

```
awk '/^00/ {f=$0;next} {print f$0}' file
00 102 | table1|1 | a|b|c
00 102 | table1|2 | c|e|f
00 101 | table100|0 | a|b|c|e|d
00 101 | table100|23| 0|1|2|3|4
00 101 | table100|34| 1|2|3|4|5
```

Comment: It's not desirable in software to test for a condition (`/^00/`) and then test for the negation of that same condition (`!/^00/`). Use `next` preferably in this situation or `if..else` in other situations.